# Let user change form background image. Save background image in the memory after close. Load background image on form load

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I made an OS in Visual Studio 2017 and added the "Change Background" option. So, this is the code to my button:

```
private void changeDesktopBackgroundToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        }
    }
```

and I want the background image to be saved for the next time the form loads. How can I do this? I think it's something with MemoryStream.

Comment: I am not sure if you can call it an "OS", 'cause it isn't really an operating system, but a concept of an operating system. Anyways, some help?

Comment: save the image temporarily somewhere, then re-load and assign it to the respective control when the _app_ oh sorry _OS_ starts.

Comment: how about using Image.Save?

Comment: Well, how can I actually do this? Okay. So, I save the image but how can I check in the Form.Load event if an image was already changed? And if yes, to load it. Else, to load the default image.

Answer (score 0):

You cant save the image in the memory in your case. Think of a real OS:

If your computer is shut down all the data in your memory is gone.
You have to save the image to one of your harddrives.
Therefore you can use this:

```
Image.Save(string filepath);
```

When you load your OS (in your case load your form) you could for example check if the image exists. If it does you load it from the harddrive and set is as the background. If the file doesnt exist you set the default backgroundimage.

You can load an image using the following code:

```
Image.FromFile(string filePath);
```

Comment: Hmm... something doesn't work here. May you tell me how to make the program save the image based on the code I wrote? I get 3 errors

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?
Show your code and ill try to fix it